# IOAT enabled but not being used with Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, intel

On our R610s with igb version 4.1.2 I do see the ioatdma module loading (and loaded with lsmod):

```
ioatdma: Intel(R) QuickData Technology Driver 4.00
ioatdma 0000:00:16.0: irq 80 for MSI/MSI-X
ioatdma 0000:00:16.1: irq 81 for MSI/MSI-X
ioatdma 0000:00:16.2: irq 82 for MSI/MSI-X
ioatdma 0000:00:16.3: irq 83 for MSI/MSI-X
ioatdma 0000:00:16.4: irq 84 for MSI/MSI-X
ioatdma 0000:00:16.5: irq 85 for MSI/MSI-X
ioatdma 0000:00:16.6: irq 86 for MSI/MSI-X
ioatdma 0000:00:16.7: irq 87 for MSI/MSI-X
```

We have a quad port Intel nic that should support it:

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
07:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
08:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

However, it looks like it isn't being used for any network traffic:

```
[root@or-rtlb01 ~]# cat /sys/class/dma/dma*/bytes*
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Does anyone know how to make it so ioat is used for network traffic?

Kernel is `Linux or-rtlb01.ds.stackexchange.com 3.7.7-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 11 22:28:07 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: redhat 6 right?

Comment: @mdpc: CentOS 6.3, tried a much newer kernel to see if it would help, but it didn't. This was a secondary issue discovered when having high si% on ksoftirqd with ipsec traffic (not that I expect offloading on the ipsec traffic itself, but would seems there is no ioatdma at all.

Comment: Does the motherboard chipset have support for IOAT? Is IOAT turned on in the system BIOS? Do you see "Intel(R) I/OAT DMA Engine found" in dmesg? This would indicate a NIC which supports IOAT has been located. Do you see "DCA is disabled in BIOS" in dmesg? This would indicate no BIOS support or enablement for DCA.

Comment: When I last asked Dell (several years ago) they said the R610 BIOS does not support DCA nor do they have plans to add support for it.

Comment: Right, as guys stated what does "dmesg |grep DCA" show?

Answer (score 4):

How big are the packets you're sending through?  By default the IOATDMA driver is only used on large packet sizes.  You can view the current setting with:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_dma_copybreak
```

If you want the value to be lower, you can set it using sysctl.  For example, to set the packet size to 1, use:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_dma_copybreak=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Before starting, update complete server like BIOS including hard drive firmware.

Secondly, always use latest Intel Network Driver `igb`. Just compile it from the source.

BIOS enable both DCA and IOATDMA. In linux try this:

`# modprobe ioatdma`

`# dmesg`

You should see the ioatdma driver loaded.

Now, the `igb` driver is different to `ixgbe` which is 10GBps one. Since I dont use `igb` at all, I can tell you to try to stop network `/etc/init.d/network stop` and `rmmod igb` and `modprobe igb` again to see if there are any differences and post results if you can pls.